# Recover deleted image links

Tags: support, links, image

If the draft of a post which I was going to publish later, is accidentally deleted, I will lose the links of the images I've already uploaded. Is there a way to recover those links?

This also applies if the link was deleted (accidentally, while trying to edit) within the grace period of five minutes after publishing the post.

Comment: Why would this recovery be necessary? Since you uploaded the images, you must have their originals and can just re-upload them again, no?

Comment: Well, then does it imply that we can't?

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re asking about cases where the link is created on the image-hosting service but then not stored in the post’s revision history?

Comment: @rob I am not familiar with your statement, but I am asking about a situation where the post has not yet been published. For instance: I make a draft and leave it to publish later. Sometimes I make another draft for another post elsewhere and then visit the site and paste the copied text over previous draft, accidentally. Then I lose the previous draft with the links of the images : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is "probably not."

When you click the "add picture" button in the editor, your image gets sent to Imgur, who re-host the image. They give your image a unique line-noise name like `AbCdE.jpg`, generate medium- and small-sized versions with names like `AbCdEm.jpg` and `AbCdEs.jpg`, and then host and serve those images for the duration of the Imgur-SE contract, which [just started its twelfth year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/).

If you re-upload your image, it'll get a new name like `fGhIj.jpg`.  The previous version is still there, but you are extremely unlikely to guess its name.  If *know* the name, you can [ask to have it deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250344/280545). But if you have forgotten the name, there is no easy way to recover that name from the private list of every image uploaded from the entire SE network.

The real problem here is probably that the SE "saved a draft" feature is kind of delicate ([see confusion here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13538/44126), [see explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291774/280545)).
Consider saving your drafts in [this Meta sandbox](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/44126), which uses the SE version history features, or using a service like https://stackedit.io/.  If you are editing version 5 of a post and you need an image link you created in version 3, you can just grab it from the edit history.